# CASE WHEN comparison resolved to NULL

Tags: sql, null, compare, case

What's the best way to write this?

I'm running through a couple of scenarios with a CASE WHEN statement. When matched on both and school then return 1. If there is no match, then match on name and school = NULL and return 2. If still no match then return 0.

ie:

```
CASE WHEN  (x.name = x.name and x.school = y.school) THEN 1
WHEN (x.name = x.name and x.school = compare and resolve to null if not matched) THEN 2
ELSE 0
```

Problem 1: How to write line 2. -- I think I have this resolved.

```
  CASE WHEN  (x.name = x.name and x.school = y.school) THEN 1
  WHEN (x.name = x.name and y.school is null) THEN 2
  ELSE 0
```

Problem 2: Once I figure out how to write the comparison for line 2, the true resolve of branch 2 will need to pick the lowest tier of the 2 null school values. In the image below, say there is no match on name and school, so the logic moves on to branch 2 comparing (name and school is null). In this case, there are two possibilities for the combination - tier 2 and tier 3.
How do I write a THEN argument to pick the lowest tier of the twe for branch 2?

[image: name]

---

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in a tabular format*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
case 
    when x.name = y.name and x.school = y.school then 1 
    when x.name = y.name and x.school is null and y.school is null then 2 
    else 0
end
```

The first branch succeeds if both `name` and `school` match. The second matches on `name`s that are equal and both `school`s having `null` values.

Comment: Possibly. 
I think I have it. Since there was no match on the first branch then I should be evaluating the match on names and y.school is null. 
case 
    when x.name = y.name and x.school = y.school then 1 
    when x.name = y.name and x.school is null then 2 
    else 0
end

Thank you!